# XPath in Python - How to Find All Elements with a Specified SubElement/SubElement.text Pair

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'm new to XML and XPath, which I'm tackling via Python. I know how to write a Python script using a simple XPath expression that does what I'm looking for, but I get the feeling that it could be slow and inelegant. I hope there's a single XPath expression that can do what I'm looking for without the need to hack my own solution.

```
<registry>
    <voter>
        <name>John</name>
        <vote>YES</vote>
    </voter>
    <voter>
        <name>Mary</name>
        <vote>NO</vote>
    </voter>
    <voter>
        <name>Luke</name>
        <vote>YES</vote>
    </voter>
    <voter>
        <name>Jane</name>
        <vote>YES</vote>
    </voter>
</registry>
```

Can you write 1 XPath expression that, from the root, returns each voter whose vote was YES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easily:

```
/registry/voter[vote='YES']
```

Consider consulting a basic [XPath tutorial](http://oreilly.com/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/ten-minute-xpath-utorial.html).